# CosmosDBTrigger: Where to specify connection string?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Using Visual Studio 2017, I created a new Azure Function app. I added a function and one of the attribute parameters is `ConnectionStringSetting`. That should be a reference to a setting stored somewhere, but I can't figure out where for the life of me.

When I try to debug the method, this is what I get back:
[image]

I have tried to put it in the `local.settings.json` file, no luck. I have tried to add an `app.config`/`appSettings` section and that doesn't do anything, either.

I am not doing anything crazy in the method:

```
namespace MyFunctions
{
    public static class TestUpdated
    {
        [FunctionName("DocumentUpdated")]
        public static void Run(
            [CosmosDBTrigger("mydb", "somecollection",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "DbConnString",
            LeaseCollectionName = "lease-test-trigger",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
            IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
            log.Info("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
        }
    }
}
```

All my extensions and nuget packages are on the latest versions.

So, how the heck do you set the connection string? It's been hours trying different things and nothing works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public static void Run(
[CosmosDBTrigger("mydb", "somecollection",
ConnectionStringSetting = "DbConnString",
LeaseCollectionName = "lease-test-trigger",
CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
```

Per my experience , `ConnectionStringSetting` should be set in App Settings.

The config would be:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "DbConnString": "...your cosmos db string..."
    }
}
```

Comment: that is in the `local.settings.json`... do these settings carry into Azure environment? If not, where do you store the connection string when you upload it?

Comment: nevermind -- it does use those settings on Azure as well. Man, the documentation is pretty bad here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To clarify, while db and collection can have actual value, the value for ConnectionString is referring to a settings and not the actual value? Is it also the same for LeaseCollectionName?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz That is correct the value for ConnectionString cannot be the actual value it must always be a reference to the settings (azure configuration or `local.settings.json`)