# Azure Functions: CosmosDBTrigger connection string storage

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625959/cosmosdbtrigger-where-to-specify-connection-string) where to store the connection string for a CosmosDBTrigger. It worked great until I had to push it up to Azure. Now the function isn't working at all. It works locally just fine though. There is no difference between codebases so the only thing I can think of is the connection string isn't be pulled from `local.settings.json` when on Azure. I mean, it wouldn't surprise me if that was the case since the file has the word `local` in it.

I tried putting the contents in the `host.json`, but that didn't work either.

How do you specify the connection string when your Function is running on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`local.settings.json` is not used in Azure. Instead, settings are taken from [App Service Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings).

For your yesterday's example, go to Function App's `Application settings` tab and add a value with key `DbConnString` there.

[image]

If you are using `func` CLI, you can publish settings from `local.settings.json` file to Azure Application settings by running

```
func azure functionapp public <App> --publish-local-settings
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. At first i added it to "ConnectionStrings" section and that didn't work. This has to go in Applications Settings of the Application Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in the Application Settings for the function app. These can be setup using the Azure Portal or deployed as part of the ARM template I believe.

[Azure Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#manage-app-service-settings)

Comment: The link's anchor goes to different type of settings, and also the screenshot is a bit out-of-date