# How do I pass in the storage account connection string for a CosmosDBTrigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to pass in a storage account connection string to a CosmosDBTrigger. I have a function that runs when there is a change on a CosmosDB container. This function copies image blobs from one container to another. If you look at the code below, I have commented out the line where I am trying to fine the storage account that I want to connect to. This function runs when that is commented out. It does not run when I have that un-commented. Why?

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("ImageCopier")]
    public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "MyDatabase", 
        collectionName: "Orders",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "databaseConnection",
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
        LeaseDatabaseName = "TriggerLeases",
        LeaseCollectionName = "TriggerLeases",
        LeaseCollectionPrefix = "ImageCopier")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, 
        //[StorageAccount("MyStorageAccount")]string storageConnectionString,
        ILogger log)
    {
```

I have MyStorageAccount defined in my local.settings.json file and I also have it in my Azure Function Configuration settings. I copied the connection string directly from the storage account keys panel.

Comment: I asked this question a couple years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625959/cosmosdbtrigger-where-to-specify-connection-string

Comment: Oh I see, you want a storage account connection string. You would probably have to store that in a configuration and use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("storageConnectionString")` to pull it during run-time. You can store it in `local.settings.json` in the `Values` array to debug locally, then put it in your configuration in Azure when you publish.

Comment: Thanks. This is working.

Comment: I will add an answer to this question so that it may help other folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up a CosmosDB trigger, the information that is supplied in that trigger is specific to the trigger. If you need a setting or configuration not related to the trigger in your code, you can use the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/environment-variables?tabs=csharp).

In your local environment, you can set these variables by editing the `local.settings.json` file, specifically the `Values` array. For example:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "JobUri": "https://yourapiendpointurl.com",
        "BlobStorageConnectionString" : "the connection string",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

In your method, you may grab that value like so:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("ImageCopier")]
    public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "MyDatabase", 
        ...
        ILogger log)
    {
        var connectionString = 
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobStorageConnectionString");
    }
}
```

The `local.settings.json` file will **not** be used when it's running in Azure.

I am not sure that when you publish the function if your `local.settings.json` file will migrate the settings to your Azure Function app's configuration, so I would check to make sure that your settings are in there after publishing.

Side note: Be carful when committing code to repos .. you don't want "secrets" in your repositories in case someone gets in to your repo and discovers it.

Answer (score 0):

While you can access raw configuration values using GetEnvironmentVariable, a more robust/idiomatic approach with .NET in particular is to leverage the [built-in dependency injection of configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings).

Using this, you can accept an IConfiguration or strongly-typed IOptions through the function's constructor and use the values in your code. For example:

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public Function1(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    [FunctionName("ImageCopier")]
    public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(/* trigger params */)] IReadOnlyList<Document> input)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration["MyStorageAccount"];

        // Use connection string
    }
}
```

You can take this further to inject services like an "ImageBlobService" into your function that have already been configured in a [common Startup Configure method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services) just like ASP.NET Core. That way the individual functions don't need to know anything about configuration and just ask for the relevant service to use.